# Change WordPress admin color scheme through CLI

Tags: wordpress, database-migration

I often update my local WordPress environment by migrating the database, based on a (mostly) WP CLI based script.

Still, both production and local environment look really similar, and it's prone to do big mistakes.

Therefore, I'd like to add an instruction to automatically change the admin color scheme for a specific user.

Is there a way to do that through WP CLI? Or, if not, with a direct-to-base operation?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it!
2 methods:

- userid based: wp user update *1* --admin_color=blue
- username based: wp user update *userlogin* --admin_color=sunrise

Source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313932/how-to-change-user-admin-color-with-wp-cli